# Struct within a struct initialization with constructor

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

Im trying to initialize my structs with constructors by sending in two other structs.

my header file Datatypes.h :

```
#ifndef __DATATYPES_H__
#define __DATATYPES_H__

struct Vertex3D {
  float x,y,z;

  Vertex3D(float x0, float y0, float z0);
};


struct Edge {
Vertex3D v0, v1;
Edge(Vertex3D v2, Vertex3D v3); 

};

#endif
```

my code Datatypes.cc

```
#include "Datatypes.h"

using namespace std;

Vertex3D::Vertex3D(float x0, float y0, float z0) {

x = x0;
y = y0;
z = z0;
}

Edge::Edge(Vertex3D v2, Vertex3D v3) {

v0 = v2;
v1 = v3;
```

The issue occurs when i try compile, and it seems like complier tries to call empty constructors in the .cc file.

So shouldn't this be working ?

Comment: Please post full compiler errors in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Edge::Edge(Vertex3D v2, Vertex3D v3) {
    v0 = v2;
    v1 = v3;
}
```

If you don't specify initializers for data members in the constructor initialization list, they will be default-constructed. There is no default constructor for `Vertex3D` objects, so you'll get a compiler error.

You should fix this by initializing the members in the initialization list:

```
Edge::Edge(Vertex3D v2, Vertex3D v3) 
  : v0(v2), v1(v3) 
{ }
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined your custom `Vertex3D(float,float,float)` constructor, the compiler is not going to make a default constructor for you any more. The default initialization on the `v2` and `v3` members of `Edge` is trying to call that non-existent constructor, hence the error.

You should initialize class members like this to avoid unnecessary copying and fix the error:

```
Vertex3D::Vertex3D(float x0, float y0, float z0) : x(x0), y(y0), z(z0) { }
```